# Connect external mongodb with private key ( file.pem ) and user without mongo_url

Tags: mongodb, meteor, connection

Hello I’m new Meteor !!!
I have only private key (file.pem), user, ip:port
I don’t know how to connect with meteor run on local machine

Answer (score 0):

First try to connect with some local client, terminal or robomongo. After you managed to do that, you can look into ways to connect your meteor application to external mongodb.

Also since meteor coming with its own bundled mongo, you should install mongodb in your system and connect your meteor app to this one mongo first.

Comment: I connected with nosqlBooster. (Done), but general i use MONGO_URL to run with Meteor on local ex:(MONGO_URL="..." meteor run) , but now i have private key(file.pem) and username , ip and port (i can connect with nosqlBooster) and i don't know how to run with meteor local

Comment: You have to specify path to .pem file in connection options https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/tutorials/connect/ssl/